# ODAC installation error for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, odac

Please help me this error is driving me insane.
First, I ran into this problem: "oracle.manageddataaccess.client not found". So, I've read that I need to install ODTwithODAC121024. Here, it says that I don't have Visual Studio installed. Good. I've searched for a solution, found on this site that i need to install first ODTforVS2019. Installed it.
I have Visual Studio (2019) installed. I have installed ODTforVS2019. Clicked it again, it says the extension is already installed. NOW, whenever I want to install this ODTwithODAC121024... I get this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8lID.png)

I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: If you can live without the Visual Studio tools, you can just get the managed NuGet packages: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess / https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/

Comment: Thank you man...I din't know what a nuget is but I installed it from visual studiom, wrote using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess; in the code and now it works...THANK YOU

Comment: NuGet is the package manager for .NET and it makes managing dependencies like 95% easier.  Remember if you're just getting started with .NET that the platform is like 20 years old.  So there's usually a "new" way and an "old" way to do everything.  Installing ODAC was the "old" way to get Oracle connectivity.